# Toshiba hdd2j13 hard drive is not showing up

Tags: hard-drive, toshiba-laptop

My Toshiba hdd2j13 hard drive is not showing up, I have a external adapter connecting it to my Windows 10 laptop

when I connect or disconnect the computer beeps, it shows up in device management and is enabled.

When I connect it I get a message saying installing USB mass hard drive progress bar.

it does not show up in disk management or files explorer.

Comment: Some screenshots might help: how it looks in Device Manager (just  that branch, expanded), of the message "installing USB mass hard drive progress bar" (is that what it says??), and in Disk Management. That said, do you have the correct adapter for that old SATA drive?

Comment: Can you hear / feel it buzz / spin? Is this a recovery attempt, was drive dropped, info info info you give use nothing.